# Objective-C returns Variable-sized object may not be initialized

Tags: ios, objective-c

come from a Java background to this Objective-c compiler error.  Why can't I specify the length of the byte array?

```
NSUInteger length = modul.length;
Byte d[length] = {0};//compiler error: Variable-sized object may not be initialized
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like I can just do  `memset(d, 0,5*sizeof(int));` to initialize it..